# How can I apply a different color to a background over a period of time?

Tags: angular, time, colors

I have an *object* with a *delivery time* property, so something like `myObject.deliveryTime`. When the `current time - myObject.deliveryTime < 4 hours` I want set my background to yellow `(#ffc107)` when `current time - myObject.deliveryTime == 4 hours` and then gradient *in real time* to `(#dc3545)` as `current time - myObject.deliveryTime == 0 hours`.

How do I get the hexadecimal to change as a function of time and keep it without the bounds of my two color values?

Gradient of colors that I'd expect to see over the course of 4 hours:
https://coolors.co/gradient-maker/dc3545-ffc107

**EDIT:**
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
https://jsfiddle.net/f9b9sbr4/1/
However, the jsfiddle goes from a darker blue to a lighter blue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by 2 options.

### Option 1

Use by ngStyle :

```
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (current_time - myObject.deliveryTime < 4) ? 
    '#ffc107' : (current_time - myObject.deliveryTime == 4) ? '#dc3545' : 'green'}">
    You content
    </div>
```

### Option 2

declare classes as per your color combination :

```
    .default-bg{
      background-color: #bfbfbf;
    }
    .red-bg{
      background-color: #dc3545;
    }
    .yellow-bg{
      background-color: #ffc107;
    }
    .green-bg{
      background-color: green;
    }
```

Use it in your html by ngClass :

```
    <p class="default-bg" [ngClass]="{'yellow-bg': current_time - 
    myObject.deliveryTime < 4,
      'red-bg': current_time - myObject.deliveryTime == 4,
      'green-bg': current_time - myObject.deliveryTime > 4}">
    Your content
    </p>
```